# Why was Luke Skywalker missing in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, luke-skywalker, behind-the-scenes

In *The Force Awakens*, we learn in the opening crawl that Luke Skywalker has disappeared.

He is in fact

> absent for most of the movie except for a few seconds at the very end (and in a vision / flashback scene).

Why was this?

I am looking both in *and* out-of-universe explanations.

**1. In-universe:** Why did this character disappear, choosing to essentially go into hiding?

**2. Out-of-universe:** Why did the filmmakers choose to

> leave this Luke Skywalker out of the main story?
>  <sub>(i.e. Did Abrams think Mark Hammill was a bad actor? Was he busy or sick? Anything like that...)</sub>

Comment: Word of God: [there is a reason](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/J-J-Abrams-Finally-Admitted-Star-Wars-7-Hiding-One-Character-90647.html) :-P

Comment: This sounds like two questions to me, in that they’re likely to have entirely different answers.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite What's wrong with that? Plenty of questions ask for in _and_ out-of-universe explanations.

Comment: @RedCaio: I guess so. I just think with this question, the two are likely unrelated. I don’t actually have anything to base that on though.

Comment: Would someone please __explain__ these downvotes? :(

Comment: I didn't downvote, but probably because the in-universe reason is clearly stated in the movie... (the tooltip for the downvote button says "this question does not show any research effort"...). I think this question could be improved by focusing on the out-of-universe reason, which is not obvious.

Comment: @AndresF. I see what you mean, but I hesitate to edit my question because I feel like it'd be unfair to those who've already answered. I don't want future viewers to downvote their answers, you know?

Comment: @RedCaio - here's an upvote to compensate (and a New Year's present: script quote in my answer update)

Comment: Also, if you choose to accept OOU answer, I would strongly recommend Rick's, since his is an actual sourced answer and not just a guess with no WoG info, as accepted answer is.

Comment: Hey, hide the spoilers...

Comment: @SS-3 I myself am a _big believer_ in hiding spoilers. However (1) it's been almost a month since TFA was released, (2) people can [add TFA to their ignored tags](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7708/how-to-avoid-star-wars-spoilers?cb=1) to avoid spoilers, (3) I feel that this question doesn't spoil any major plot points, and (4) the question title was way to vague in spoiler-free form  :)

Comment: (1) One month is nothing. It hasn't yet been released to entire world. (2) With that logic, you won't hide spoiler anywhere. This is wrong. Although people can, they don't always do that. (3) It is broadcasting a major plot point. Lots of people expect to see Luke in the movie. (4) No. It's not.

Comment: Meta: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7849/is-this-spoiler-acceptable

Comment: Anyone who's seen the movie will know who the title is referring to, even with the spoilery-bit removed. Hiding tags doesn't help when things show up on the sidebar.

Comment: Also, using the actor's name in the title kind of defeats hiding the name of the character he portrays.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Out of universe:**

Because they thought Luke would draw the attention away from the other new lead characters

According to an [article from ScreenRant.com](http://screenrant.com/star-wars-7-luke-skywalker-role-explained/):

> Early on I tried to write versions of the story where [Rey] is at home, her home is destroyed, and then she goes on the road and meets Luke. And then she goes and kicks the bad guy’s ass. It just never worked and I struggled with this. This was back in 2012.
>
> It just felt like every time Luke came in and entered the movie, he just took it over. Suddenly you didn’t care about your main character anymore because, ‘Oh [wow], Luke Skywalker’s here. I want to see what he’s going to do.’
>   <sub>- Michael Arndt</sub>

**In universe:**

Sometime after the events of *Return of the Jedi*, Luke

> started training a new generation of Jedi. When one of them turned to the *Dark Side* and killed the others, Luke held himself responsible so he went into exile.

Comment: Great quote. This very nicely answers the question asked.

Comment: @Richard - This should be the accepted answer (at least if OP prefers OOU half of his question) and I recommended that to OP

Comment: Nice OOU (out-of-universe) answer. Maybe you could add IU (in-universe) too, for completeness. :)

Comment: @RedCaio Added it :)

Comment: @RickSanchez congrats on stealing the acceptance from another user. You get to feel a sense of accomplishment while I get to feel guilty for unaacepting the other user's answer. :) lol

Comment: @RedCaio thanks :) . I half-expected I'd get a thief badge though. Maybe scifi.stackexchange should add one ^_^

Comment: Jedi going into exile because they screwed up seems to be something of a trend. Woo.

Answer (score 17):

**In universe:**

> As Han explains. The new Jedi order had been destroyed. He had failed and unleashed a new terror on the Galaxy. He needed some space

**Out of universe:**

I think there needed to be space for the new characters to grow.

> It was also some misdirection to keep us guessing. Mark was part of all the PR and very excited about the film. We were meant to believe he was a full part of the film.

It wasn't till the later trailers came out that people started asking 'where is Luke?'
And JJ [said](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/star-wars-missing-luke-skywalker-834885)

> These are good questions to be asking. I can't wait for you to find out the answers,

Comment: I can't fathom that the producers expected this misdirection "trick" to lead to anything but disappointment. What a silly decision.

Comment: They were trying their best to keep the plot under wraps. Saying how much screen time various characters have would at least hint as to plot elements.

Comment: Right, so they should have just kept him out of it.

Comment: Sorry about the unaccept, these things happen. :( Your answer is still great though. :)

Comment: NP the accepted one is better.

Answer (score 14):

### Out of universe: because no beard.

From a [very recent interview](http://www.rollingstone.com/movies/news/skywalker-speaks-mark-hamill-on-returning-to-star-wars-20151218) with Mark Hamill:

> Hamill was just starting to regrow his Jedi beard for the follow-up, Episode VIII — which would soon need him on set. He had shaved to play the Trickster on the new season of The Flash, and had to ask Lucasfilm's permission to do so. "The bottom line was if I couldn't grow it back fast enough, I couldn't do the part," says Hamill, 64. "Luckily, I have 10 weeks, so fingers crossed!"

Comment: Best out of universe answer ever.

Comment: @CandiedMango Then where's my +1? :-[ :-P

Comment: It won't be available for 10 weeks, it's growing a beard.

Comment: @CandiedMango rofl

Comment: I suspect the in-universe answer is "you'll find out in the next film", but I'm not confident enough in my SW knowledge to put that in my answer. @CandiedMango what do you think?

Comment: In-universe is the reason for why he ran away, although more will be revealed I'd say he was probably waiting to be found.

Comment: but... in that quote he's talking about needing to have a beard for *Ep. 8*, not Ep. 7...

Comment: This quote isn't about TFA

Comment: I don't think that this answer is an out-of-universe explanation on *why* Luke is not more present in the movie, but a consequence of the real explanation. *If* J.J.Abrams/Lucasfilms wanted more of Luke in the show, they would just have refused Mark Hamill to play the Trickster in the Flash. The presence of Hamill in the Flash (a part of DC Universe, the direct competitor of Marvel Cinematic Universe, the other big project of Disney) is a strong hint that Hamill was not important for the Episode 7.

Comment: @Taladris - arguably, he wasn't that important for Episode 4 either :) </luke_bashing>

Comment: I don't buy the "need time to grow a beard" explanation, either. The makeup department could simply put a fake beard on him and make it look real. Something else had to be going on.

Comment: @DVK Thanks for the bounty! I hadn't realised you'd put one on this question, nor that my answer was bounty-worthy, so that was unexpected :-) Also, have an upvote on yours - I hadn't upvoted it before, since you were repcapping every day back then.

Answer (score 12):

### In-universe

Han Solo explains it to Rey:

- Luke basically pulled an Obi-Wan and trained Vader Jr. Almost literally.
- And then he pulled a Amazing Disappearing Yoda trick.

  Luke learned well from his past Masters :)

WGA script:

> **REY**
> Why'd he leave?
> **HAN**
> He was training a new generation of Jedi. One boy, an apprentice turned against him, destroyed it all. Luke felt responsible... He walked away from everything

Alan Dean Foster's novelization:

> Rey spoke while drinking in the details of the marvelous but imperfect chart. “Why’d he leave, anyway?”
> Han pursed his lips; thinking back, remembering.
> “He was training a new generation of Jedi. There was no one else left to do it, so he took the burden on himself. **Everything was going good, until one boy, an apprentice, turned against him and destroyed it all. Everything Luke had worked toward: gone. Luke felt responsible. He walked away from everything.**”
> Finn’s tone was respectful. “Do you know what happened to him? Does anyone?”
> Han turned to him. “There’ve been all kinds of rumors and stories. When people don’t have access to facts, they invent what they’d like to believe, or what they think others would like to hear. The people who knew him the best think he went on a personal quest, looking for the first Jedi temple.”

### Out of universe

First of all, [@RickSanchez's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/113148/976) is totally awsome and probably better at addressing OOU than what I found.

But I found a slightly different, complementary reasoning to the one he cited. During Guild Screenings Q&A with the screenwriters, [J.J. Abrams said](http://www.wga.org/content/default.aspx?id=6130) about his reason to agree to work on the reboot, that it was an exciting idea to explore in terms of...:

> “**Luke Skywalker is potentially an unknown. Luke Skywalker is potentially a myth**. Luke Skywalker, is like, you know, King Arthur. To someone who’s 19 years old, what does that mean?”

Admittely, most of the famous Arthuriana deals with actually-active King Arthur, not a shut-off in exile King Arthur, but we'll forgive that inaccuracy because NO MIDICHLORIANS!

Comment: There is already a novelization you can buy!? :O But... the movie...

Comment: @AndresF. - digital version. Dead tree will be January release